# Django Page not found error on url redirect

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

So I'm dealing with a little problem here. So what i wanna do is: sign up an user, then redirect him to a new page that contains a form which will collect some additional info about him and then after he submits the form, it should redirect him to the login page.
I want this version because only new users should complete this form.

signup view

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_ski_experience:user_questions')
    template_name = "signup/signup.html"
```

additional info view

```
class CreateInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = AdditionalInfoModel

    form_class = AdditionallnfoModelForm
    template_name = "user_ski_experience/additional_info.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        variable_to_send = super(CreateInfoView, 
             self).get_form_kwargs()
        variable_to_send.update({'pk': None})
        variable_to_send.update({'pk_user': self.request.user.pk})
        return variable_to_send

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('login')
```

Comment: Which redirect is it returning the 404 on? What URL is it giving when it delivers the 404? Are you certain that URL is correct for the given page? (The fact that it's a 404 suggests that it isn't.)

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/user_info/ this one